# creating a file in "System32\sysprep" with C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a program to prepare and run sysprep on both windows 7 and windows 10 machines(based on particular variables).

I have created standardized XML files for each operating system, but am having issues during creation to the effect that the program decides to place the file in SysWOW64.

I have since changed the program to be x86 based to try and avoid this which didn't work. I have also tried to embed scripts for CMD using "XCopy" to specifically move the file which is still not working. below is the pertinent parts of the code that I am trying to make work without success.

```
try
    {
        using (StreamWriter Unattend = new StreamWriter("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sysprep\\unattend.xml"))
    {
        Unattend.WriteLine("<settings pass=\"generalize\">");
        Unattend.Write("</unattend>");
    }
    }
catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed Create XML File");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File-System Redirection can be disabled with a p/Invoke call to the kernel.

Taken from http://www.tonycamilli.com/blog/2005/07/disabling-wow64-file-system:

```
class Wow64Mgr
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        try
        {
        if(Wow64Interop.EnableWow64FSRedirection(false))
            Console.WriteLine("WOW64 File System Redirection Disabled");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Failure Disabling WOW64 File System Redirection");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure Setting WOW64 File System Redirection.");
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class Wow64Interop
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.Dll", EntryPoint="Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection")]
    public static extern bool EnableWow64FSRedirection(bool enable);
}
```

This can have all kinds of crazy side-effect, so **DO NOT** leave it disabled.  You should turn it off immediately before writing your file, and turn it back on as soon as it is done.

Comment: Wow, that is a bit weird. Never would I imagine that I would have to go to a Kernel level in order to set a file. Thank you for your assistance. since obviously I'm not that good at this yet I'm going to just ask. once I instantiate the class for Wow64Interop to change the configuration all I should need to do is to call Wow64Interop.EnableWow64FSRedirection([either true or false]); Thank you again

Comment: You shouldn't even need to instantiate it, since it's declared as static, but yes, you are correct. Call it once with false to disable it, then again with true to turn it back on.